# Teflon pan safe to use after being in an oven?

Tags: teflon

We put a Teflon pan in the oven at 400° F for about 20 minutes before we realized and took it out.After it cools off outside and we wash it would it still be safe to use on the stove? or should we toss it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the pan should be just fine to use because Teflon begins to deteriorate at temperatures of 500 degrees Fahrenheit or more according to the Wikipedia article on PTFE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytetrafluoroethylene).